# document.getElementById with ClientID for UserControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have written the following JavaScript code as below

```
function confirmCallBackFn(arg)
{
    if (arg == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('#<%=txtOne.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

In page view source I get as below

```
document.getElementById('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser1_MyContainer1_txtOne').disabled = true;
```

The `txtOne` textbox does not get disabled.

**EDIT** ***************************************************************

The following is the code I am using for RadNumericTextBox

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" MaxValue="1440" MinValue="0"
                                                Width="35px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtOne_TextChanged">
                                                <%--Value='<%# (int)Eval("MyValue") %>'--%>
                                                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
                                            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Checkbox1_checkedchanged event is as follows

```
protected void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to clear controls?", "confirmCallBackFn", 300, 100, null, "");
}
```

Comment: Did you try without the `#` symbol? It should be used with jQuery but not with `document.getElementById`.

Comment: I have removed # also. But it does not work. By the way, the textbox control is a telerik control

Comment: Your `arg` is probably false or not a boolean. The code to disable a textbox is correct after you remove the `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to get the client-side object

All the API methods are accessible via the registered JavaScript objects for each control.A global variable with the same name as the ClientID of the control is available for each control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var numeric = $find("<%= RadNumericTextBox1.ClientID %>")
    }
</script>
```

Another approach for getting the client-side object is to handle any client-side event of the control - the sender argument references the desired client object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = null;
    function Load(sender, args) {
        textBox = sender;
    }
</script>
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadNumericTextBox1" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents OnLoad="Load" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

You can learn more about his by looking for [Client-side Programming of your control in the Telerik Documentation.](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/numerictextbox/client-side-programming/overview)

I hope this will help.

Edit: 
This stample work for me :

```
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" Text="now you see me ?"  >
    </telerik:RadTextBox>

    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="RadButton" OnClientClicked="DoIT"  ></telerik:RadButton>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DoIT() {
            var bbbbb = $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>");
            bbbbb.disable();
        }

    </script>
```

[If you want to learn more about Client side method and properties of a control.](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/numerictextbox/client-side-programming/radnumerictextbox-client-object)

[Some exmple in the telerik Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/textbox/programming/client-side/api/defaultcs.aspx)

Regards,
Pierre

Comment: In the process of simplifying the question, I have not revealed something. I am using checkbox1_CheckedChanged event. This checkbox is an asp control and on uncheck of this, I am calling RadConfirm and this in turn is calling "confirmCallBackFn". In this function on client side, I need to disable the txtOne textbox. I cannot call OnLoad like this. It is coming from Server side.

Comment: Did you try the  : var numeric = $find("<%= RadNumericTextBox1.ClientID %>")  ;  instead of the  document.getElementById('txtOne')  ?

Comment: Should I use numeric.disabled = false, then? Even then it is not working, the RadNumericTextBox is not getting disabled.

Comment: RadNumericTextBox  has a "set_visible" property.

Comment: There comes the clue for me. It is working well for last UserControl of the page. The UserControl is repeated multiple times in a Webpage. Could you please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Where you have modified the code. It is the same code only.

Comment: Here is a working stample from me. I think you can adapt this to your need. Tell me if its ok

Comment: I am stuck here. I got the answer from you but the page is containing multiple usercontrols, and it is working correctly for the last usercontrol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122915/discussion-between-pierre-lebon-and-cpk-2011).

Answer (score 0):

Please put ClientIDMode="Static" in your TextBox Like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I am using Telerik:RadNumericTextBox and when I put ClientIDMode="Static", the confirmation dialog box is not coming. I am disabling the control only on confirmation

Answer (score -1):

You can directly pass an ID of the textbox inside the function

```js
function confirmCallBackFn(arg)
{
    if (arg == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('txtOne').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a page with user control in it. Inside UserControl, I am having other usercontrol in it. In this UserControl, I am having txtOne textbox control and I want to disable this txtOne textbox. I have tried your code and it does not work.

Comment: ok. then u use F12 and check what is your textbox's id, then use that ID.

Comment: document.getElementById(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser1_MyContainer1_txtOne).disabled = true; Even this does not work